# PUT Request with content type : text/html not working

Tags: node.js, header, http-headers, request-headers

I am currently working in node, I need to understand put request method with access control allow headers, Below is my code

```
 import express from 'express'; 
    import cors from 'cors';
    const app = express();
    var corsOptions = {
       origin: '*',
       optionsSuccessStatus: 200, 
       allowedHeaders:['Content-Type: text/html'] 
    }
    app.put("/puttest", (req, res) =>  {
            console.log('in put');
            res.send({ 'message': ' Hello world !!! app is listening on port '})        
    });
   app.listen(3001, () => { 
        console.log('Listening to requests on 3001'); 
   });
```

It is not working why? can you please help me why it is not working when I provide any content-type: application/JSON or text/HTML?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y97hi.png)

Comment: Can you also add the error and the request you are making? It will help to understand exactly what is failing.

Comment: First thing I can notice is you have not configured cors properly. You need to add `app.use(cors(corsOptions));` to add cors to all routes and if you want to add that to your specific route then do `app.put("/puttest", cors(corsOptions) ,(req, res) => ....`.